# chrome.storage.local.get and set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use `chrome.storage.local` in my extension, and it doesn't seem to work. I used `localStorage` but realized that I can't use it in content scripts over multiple pages.

So, this is what I've come up with:

```
function save()
{
    var channels = $("#channels").val();
    var keywords = $("#keywords").val();

    chrome.storage.local.set({'channels': channels});
    chrome.storage.local.set({'keywords': keywords});
}
```

I do believe I'm doing the `save()` right, but the problem comes up in `load()`:

```
function load()
{
    var channels = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get('channels', function(result){
        channels = result;
        alert(result);
    });

    var keywords = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get('keywords', function(result){
        keywords = result;
        alert(result);
    });

    $("#channels").val(channels);
    $("#keywords").val(keywords);
}
```

When the alerts trigger, it prints out `[object Object]`. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? I looked at the documentation/examples, but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
function load() {
    var channels = "";
    var keywords = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get('channels', function (result) {
        channels = result.channels;
        alert(result.channels);
        $("#channels").val(channels);
    });
}
```

[Chrome.storage.local.get()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get) returns an object with items in their key-value mappings, so you have to use the index of the key in your search pattern.

#### IMP:

Thanks to Rob for identifying: [Chrome.storage.local.get()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get) is [**asynchronous**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#sync), you should modify your code to ensure they work after callback() is successful.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can a single code block be used to return all keys?

Comment: Better to declare variables in callback function instead of declaring them globally. Just saying :)

Answer (score 6):

debug or use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

for more details as to what you are getting back

Comment: console.dir(result); will also do this.

Answer (score 2):

The "result" value you are using is an object that contains the storage value, to get the value you have to use `result.keywords`, which will get the value of the keywords. EX:

```
function load(){
  chrome.storage.local.get('keywords', function(result){
    var keywords = result.keywords;
    alert(keywords);
  });

  chrome.storage.local.get('channels', function(result){
    var channels = result.channels;
    alert(channels);
  });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't deal with the main problem of using `keywords` later in the code, but before the callback runs.