# Chrome.Local.Storage update for html5 localstorage Chrome Packaged apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm trying to update my chrome apps to have some new manifest features but I have to rewrite some of code to do so. Here are examples of local storage get item that I believe I need to use either `chrome.local.storage` or sync.

```
        var name = 'chrome-writer-files';
        document.forms.editor.doc1.value = localStorage.getItem(name);

        var name = 'chrome-writer-files2';
        document.forms.editor.doc2.value = localStorage.getItem(name);

        var name = 'chrome-writer-files3';

        document.forms.editor.doc3.value = localStorage.getItem(name);
```

Please let me know how I can rewrite this so I don't get the error.

Comment: Maybe share the error you are getting?

Comment: This is the error. Uncaught window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead.

Comment: Did you try `chrome.storage.local.getItem(name)` instead of `localStorage.getItem(name)`

Comment: Yes I tried that I'm getting "Has no method 'getItem'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `chrome.storage.local.get()` instead.

Learn more: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get

Full example: ([Chrome - chrome.storage.local.get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872542/chrome-chrome-storage-local-get-and-set))

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'someItem': 'some value'});

chrome.storage.local.get('someItem', function (result) {
    alert(result);     
});
```

Comment: I know I've been going through that it just doesn't make much sense.  I tried this too. var name = 'chrome-writer-files';
         document.forms.editor.doc1.value = chrome.storageArea.get(name);

Comment: Thanks that is a valid way I'll try to rewrite my function now.