# window.local storage is not available in packaged apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to make a Chrome app that allows you to upload code to an Arduino (I know there's already some that do that, but I want to make my own) and when I try to run the app I get an error in background.js that says this:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpokx.png)

I only have the basic window in my background.js though

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the error has the solution to your question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome.Local.Storage update for html5 localstorage Chrome Packaged apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046844/chrome-local-storage-update-for-html5-localstorage-chrome-packaged-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says: "window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead."

Where you are referring to `window.localStorage`, replace `window.localStorage` with `chrome.storage.local`.

Comment: @JordanBaron You surely do. Try a global search for the string localStorage, including all of your libraries.

Comment: I also thought that I did not reference localStorage, until I did as Jordan suggested and I found that localForage checked for the presence of localStorage