# Chrome.storage.local Can't access data in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, storage, local

This is a chrome extension and there are 2 scripts involved 1st is for the settings page(default_popup) and the second is for actions with a certain webpage. All is fine in the settings page but when i try to access data in the second script i get nothing. Any pointers would be appreciated! Will add code on request, just tell me what you want to see.

[manifest]

```
{

    "name" : "TEST",

    "description" : "it just works",

    "version" : "1.0",

    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent",
        "storage"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [This is filled in the original],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"]
        }
    ],

    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

[input.js]

```
$(function(){


window.onload = function() {


    updateval();


    document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(){
        var value1 = document.getElementById('input_refresh').value;
        var value2 = document.getElementById('input_max').value;
        var value3 = document.getElementById('input_min').value;
        var value4 = document.getElementById('input_disc').value;
        //alert(value);
          chrome.storage.local.set({
            'ref'   :   value1,
            'max'   :   value2,
            'min'   :   value3,
            'disc'  :   value4
                }, function(){
                    console.log('Values saved');

                    $("#save").val("Saved!");

                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#save").val("Save Settings");    
                    }, 2000);
          });
    }

    document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function(){

          chrome.storage.local.set({
            'ref'   :   10,
            'max'   :   999999,
            'min'   :   0,
            'disc'  :   30
                }, function(){
                    updateval();
                    console.log('Values got reset');

                    $("#reset").val("Reset!");  

                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#reset").val("Reset To Default");    
                    }, 2000);

          });
    }

    }


function updateval (){


            chrome.storage.local.get([
            'ref',
            'max',
            'min',
            'disc'
                ], function(data){
                    $('#input_refresh').val(data.ref);
                    $('#input_max').val(data.max);
                    $('#input_min').val(data.min);
                    $('#input_disc').val(data.disc);
                    console.log('Values Gotten');
        });


}

})();
```

[script.js]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         chrome.storage.local.get([
         'ref',
         'max',
         'min',
         'disc'
            ], function(data){
               var ref    = data.ref;
               var max        = data.max;
               var min        = data.min;
               var disc   = data.disc;
               console.log('Values Gotten');
      });

if(window.location.href.indexOf("") > -1) {
    //console.log("homepage");
    main();
}
});

function main() { additional code here}
```

Comment: can you please post your code

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First u need to parse the object

> JSON.stringify(result)

Here u can refer [chrome.storage.local.get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872542/chrome-chrome-storage-local-get-and-set)