# How do I get elements that were created using the DOM instead of HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use `document.getElementsByClassName`, but when I did that it gave me a collection of elements like this:

```
HTMLCollection(2)
0: button#1.remove
1: button#2.remove
length: 2
2: <unreadable>
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

When I tried to iterate through it there was nothing in the HTML Collection. I also tried to find the length of the HTML Collection, but it said it was 0. Also these buttons were created using JavaScript. The buttons created using HTML I am able to iterate through.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('submit-note').addEventListener('click', add, false);
    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clear, false);
    document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', copy, false);
    updateNotes();
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(updateNotes);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          add();
        }
      });
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    console.log(elements);
    console.log(elements.length);
    for (item of elements) { 
        console.log(item);
      } 
})

function updateNotes() {
    document.getElementById("note-container").innerHTML = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get(['notes'], function (result) {
        var curNotes = result.notes;
        console.log(curNotes)
        if (curNotes) {
            for (var i = 0; i < curNotes.length; i++) {
                var parsedDate = new Date(JSON.parse(curNotes[i].date))
                var hour = parsedDate.getHours().toString() + ":" + parsedDate.getMinutes() + "am";
                if (parsedDate.getHours() > 12) {
                    hour = parsedDate.getHours() - 12;
                    hour = hour.toString() + ":" + parsedDate.getMinutes() + "pm";
                }
                
                var greatNote = document.createElement("div")
                var fullNote = document.createElement("div")
                var deleteContianer = document.createElement("div");

                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode(curNotes[i].note);
                para.appendChild(node);

                var date = document.createElement("p");
                var dateNode = document.createTextNode(`${parsedDate.getMonth() + 1}/${parsedDate.getDate()}/${parsedDate.getFullYear()} - ${hour}`);
                date.appendChild(dateNode);

                fullNote.appendChild(para);
                fullNote.appendChild(date);

                var remove = document.createElement("button")
                remove.innerHTML = "D";
                remove.id = curNotes[i].id.toString();
                deleteContianer.appendChild(remove);
                
                var element = document.getElementById("note-container");
                greatNote.appendChild(fullNote);
                greatNote.appendChild(deleteContianer);
                element.appendChild(greatNote);

                para.classList.add('note-text');
                date.classList.add('date-text');
                fullNote.classList.add('full-note');
                remove.classList.add('remove');
                greatNote.classList.add('great-note')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome.storage.local.get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872542/chrome-storage-local-get-and-set) -- When you call `updateNotes()` It is calling that asynchronous function and it is its callback that creates the `.remove` class elements you look for. So when calling `console.log(elements.length)`, a couple lines after... The async callback has not executed yet.

Comment: Try `async` in front of `function updateNotes() {` and `await` in front of `updateNotes();`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you for the help, unfortunately when I added await and async nothing changed. I changed line 5 to await updateNotes(); and I changed line 20 to async function updateNotes() {. I also added async on line because the function needs to be async to have await in it. Is there anything else I can try or that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

That was my first comment:

> When you call updateNotes() It is calling that asynchronous function and it is its callback that creates the .remove class elements you look for. So when calling console.log(elements.length), a couple lines after... The async callback has not executed yet.

What I forgot to tell is to add `new Promise()` somewhere.

So you have to add `await` in front of `updateNotes()` because that is where you need to wait. But it has to be a promise, else it is considered an already resolved promise... And won't wait. See [await documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

So here is what I would try (I skipped a couple lines for clarity):

```
async function functionName (){
  // ...
  await updateNotes();
  // ...
}

async function updateNotes() {
  return new Promise( resolve =>{
  
    document.getElementById("note-container").innerHTML = "";
    await chrome.storage.local.get(['notes'], function (result) {
      // ...
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I added the new Promise that you suggested, but nothing changed. This is what I have now:

async function updateNotes() {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        document.getElementById("note-container").innerHTML = "";
        await chrome.storage.local.get(['notes'], function (result) {
        //...
        }
   })
}